# Accessing instance variables in lib folder in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible to access `instance variable` defined in a `controller` by a method inside my `lib` folder? Consider the class `DoSomething` in my lib folder

```
# inside /lib folder
class DoSomething

    def fun
        puts @some_text
    end

end


class SampleController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @some_text = "ha ha ha"
    DoSomething.new().fun
  end

end
```

This does not print anything. I can pass the value to method but I wanna know is it possible to do it without that?

Comment: Well no; that makes no sense. What are you trying to do? Do you actually want some form of mixin?

Comment: @DaveNewton I have functionality which manipulates lot of instance variables and is used in multiple controllers, so I thought of moving the common code to a lib file, so it could be accessed across controllers.

Comment: Then you want some sort of mixin, not a completely isolated class. Or you can pass the instance to the library class and manipulate visible instance vars like any other class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access it directly, but you can pass it to the initializer for DoSomething:

```
# inside /lib folder
class DoSomething

  def initialize(some_text)
    @some_text = some_text
  end

  def fun
    puts @some_text
  end
end


class SampleController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @some_text = "ha ha ha"
    DoSomething.new(@some_text).fun
  end
end
```